# react-native push notification is not working in background

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-fcm

i am using react-native-fcm to receive the push notification.it is properly working  when app notification screen is in foreground state only(not working on other screens).But i want  receive a notification when app is killed or in the background or i am on any other screen of my project.Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import FCM,{FCMEvent,RemoteNotificationResult,WillPresentNotificationResult,NotificationType} from "react-native-fcm";

let data=[];
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async(notify)=>{
  if(notify.local_notification){
    //this is a local notification
    console.log('===data  =====on=='+JSON.stringify(notify))
  }
  if(notify.opened_from_tray){
    console.log("====tray=======")
  }
  if(Platform.OS==='android'){
    switch(notify.NotificationType){
      case NotificationType.Remote:
      notify.finish(
        RemoteNotificationResult.NewData  
      )                   
      break;
      case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
      notify.finish();
      break;
      case NotificationType.WillPresent:
      notify.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All)
      break;
    }           
  }
});
FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken,(token)=>{
  console.log(token);
})

export default class HomePage extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      totalTarget: null,
      targetAchieved:null,
      message:null,
      notificationsType:null,
      extraMessage:null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    FCM.requestPermissions().then(()=>console.log('granted')).catch(()=>console.log('notification permission'))

    FCM.getFCMToken().then(token=>{
      console.log(token)
    });

    this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async(notify)=>{
      console.log("===notification---listener===="+JSON.stringify(notify));
      this.setState({
        totalTarget:notify.totalTarget,
        targetAchieved:notify.targetAchieved,
        message:notify.message,
        notificationsType:notify.notificationsType,
        extraMessage:notify.extraMessage
      })
      navigate("TargetScreenPage",{message:this.state.message,extraMessage:this.state.extraMessage})
    })

    FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notify=>{
      console.log("notification-----"+ JSON.stringify(notify))

    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.notificationListener.remove();           
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.totalTarget}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.targetAchieved}
        </Text>

         <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.message}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.notificationsType}
        </Text>
     <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.extraMessage}
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```